# Why do I get an error for [RNFirebaseMessaging instance]?

Tags: react-native-firebase

As per the instructions at https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/notifications/ios , I added the following to my AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
   [[RNFirebaseNotifications instance] didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

However, I get this error:

> No known class method for selector 'instance'

**Question 1:** Why?

Note: I'm not importing `RNFirebaseNotifications.h`

Answer (score 0):

The docs for setup react-native-firebase and settings up the Messaging / Notification modules are really confusing.

Import BOTH:

```
#import "RNFirebaseNotifications.h"
#import "RNFirebaseMessaging.h"
```

and it should fix your issue.